Assistance to fix query to identify recursive relationships in data in SQL DW
I have a table which has hierarchical relationships.
My input data is
product_identifier  parent_product_identifier  Zone
------------------  -------------------------  ----
1                   5                          E
2                   6                          F
3                   7                          G
4                   8                          H
5                   11                         R 
6                   12                         B
7                   13                         C
8                   14                         D
11                  15                         A

And expected output is :
product  parent_product_identifier  hierarchy  zone
-------  -------------------------  ---------  ----
1        5                          3          A
2        6                          2          B
3        7                          2          C
4        8                          2          D 
5        11                         2          A

I did try this approach :
with parent as (
  select
    product_identifier,
    parent_product_identifier,
    Zone,
    1 AS hierarchy,
  from
    temp
),
child as (
  select
    product_identifier,
    parent_product_identifier,
    Zone,
    p.hierarchy + 1,
  from
    temp c
  inner join
    parent p
  on
    c.parent_product_identifier = p.product_identifier
  and zone is not null
)
  select
    product_identifier,
    parent_product_identifier,
    Zone,
    hierarchy
  from
    parent
  union all
    select
    product_identifier,
    parent_product_identifier,
    Zone,
    hierarchy
  from
    child

But i am unable to achieve hierarchy of 3
how can i fix my query?
Note : my version of SQL DW does not support recursion.
Is there any other way to do the same.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.

Now it looks better but your "expected" output is suspiciously like the actual outcome. It's supposed to be the what you want to get, not what you're getting

The goal is to detemine the hierarchy and the ultimate zone

@ThomA, apologies, we have now question in format,  as expected.

That query was a beast. There probably is a better way.

DBFiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/jSdYcwWM

WITH dt AS (
  --add the root potion of the recursion
  SELECT
    temp.product_identifier,
    temp.parent_product_identifier,
    temp.Zone,
    1 AS hierarchy,
    parent_product_identifier AS current_parent --used to keep track as we walk the parents
  FROM temp

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
     dt.product_identifier, 
     dt.parent_product_identifier, 
     temp.Zone, 
     dt.hierarchy+1, --increase by one as we walk up the chain
     temp.parent_product_identifier AS current_parent
  FROM dt
     INNER JOIN temp
     ON temp.product_identifier = dt.current_parent
)
SELECT 
  product_identifier,
  parent_product_identifier,
  hierarchy,
  Zone
FROM dt
WHERE hierarchy > 1                                      --exclude rows that don't have a parent present
AND hierarchy = (
   SELECT MAX(hierarchy) FROM dt dt2 
   WHERE dt2.product_identifier = dt.product_identifier) --exclude rows we used along the way to build the recursion
ORDER BY product_identifier;


Thanks for your answer but my version of SQL DW, does not support recursion. Is there any other way, i can do the same.

My first approach was going to be a table variable that you populate with the initial values from temp, and then use a WHILE loop to keep updated values in the table as you find their parents, and their parents, using their tier and increasing hiearchy by one each time, until @@rowcount = 0 meaning no more rows were affected by the update, and you've found no more parents.

I tried something on those lines but unable to achieve expected result. let me close this as you do have a solution , just not applicable in my case

I had a slight change in requirement also but updated question and my approach is here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78309647/stored-procedure-logic-fix-needed-for-parent-child-relationships-in-data-running
