Stored procedure logic fix needed for parent child relationships in data running on Synapse
I have a table which has hierarchical relationships.
Because I am using synapse, I can’t use recursion, so trying this below approach using a stored procedure.
My input data is :
---------------------------------------------------------
|product_identifier |parent_product_identifier|Zone|Flag|
--------------------|-------------------------|----|----|
|1                  |   5                     |  E |   N|
|2                  |   6                     |  F |   N|
|3                  |   7                     |  G |   N|                       
|4                  |   8                     |  H |   N|                       
|5                  |   11                    |  R |   N|                       
|6                  |   12                    |  B |   Y|                       
|7                  |   13                    |  C |   Y|                       
|8                  |   14                    |  D |   Y|                       
|11                 |   15                    |  A |   Y|
---------------------------------------------------------                       

And expected output is :
---------------------------------------------
product | parent_product_identifier | region |
----------------------------------------------
1        5                            A
2        6                            B
3        7                            C
4        8                            D 
5        11                           A
6        12                           B

The idea here is to get the region value based on ultimate parents zone (for flag value as Y)
But I am unable to achieve the expected result.
How can I fix my stored procedure?
I wrote this stored procedure:
CREATE PROCEDURE UPDATEHIERARCHIES 
AS
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #x 
    (
        ZONE NVARCHAR(1), 
        product_identifier NVARCHAR(200), 
        parent_product_identifier NVARCHAR(200)
    );

    INSERT INTO #x (
        SELECT ZONE, product_identifier, parent_product_identifier
        FROM PRODUCT
        WHERE FLAG = ‘Y’;

    DECLARE @ROWCOUNT INT = 1;

    WHILE @ROWCOUNT > 0 
    BEGIN
        UPDATE c
        SET c.region = p.zone
        FROM PRODUCT c
        INNER JOIN #x p ON c.parent_product_identifier = p.product_identifier
        WHERE Flag = ’N’;

        DELETE FROM #x;
    
        INSERT INTO #x 
            SELECT ZONE, product_identifier, parent_product_identifier
            FROM PRODUCT
            WHERE parent_product_identifier IN 
                  (SELECT product_identifier FROM #x)

        SET @ROWCOUNT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #x)
    END;

    DROP TABLE #x;
END;


can you try in INSERT INTO statement, you have used single quotes around the letter Y. try replace them with double quotes.
